# Java Graphics not drawing inside if else or recursion

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw a tree of life sort of thing using an Icon in java and it isn't drawing correctly.
Below is the code that my paintIcon method calls in order to draw out the tree. I later added the code
at the end that is outside of any if statements and that draws correctly as long as it is the paintIcon method that calls draw. The recursive call of draw and any g.drawString or g.drawLine lines inside the if statements do not draw anything. Is there any reason why this would happen? Sorry if this is too much or too little information.

```
public void draw(Taxon t, Graphics2D g, int xStep, int yStep) {
        if(!t.isDrawn()) {
            // does special action if drawing a leaf
            if(t.getChildren().size() == 0) {
                //leaves are all aligned on the right and get drawn in a column
                t.setX(width - 100);
                t.setY(50 + yStep * leafCount);
                g.drawString(t.getName(), t.getX(), t.getY());
                leafCount++;
                t.setDrawn(true);
                System.out.print("leaf");
            }
            else {
                //draws all the children first
                for(Taxon c : t.getChildren()) {
                    draw(c, g, yStep, xStep);
                }
                
                //x needs to be x step away from children while y is in the middle
                t.setX(t.getChildren().get(0).getX() - xStep);
                int average = 0;
                for(Taxon c : t.getChildren()) {
                    average += c.getY();
                }
                t.setY(average / t.getChildren().size());
                
                //draw connecting lines
                for(Taxon c : t.getChildren()) {
                    g.drawLine(t.getX(), t.getY(), c.getX(), c.getY());
                }
                
                //getting info for filling up space behind node text since lines might overlap
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                Rectangle2D r = fm.getStringBounds(t.getName(), g);
                
                //draw the highlight then the text itself
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(t.getX(), t.getY() - fm.getAscent(), (int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(t.getName(), t.getX(), t.getY());
                t.setDrawn(true);
                System.out.print("node");
            }
        }
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        Rectangle2D r = fm.getStringBounds(t.getName(), g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(t.getX(), t.getY() - fm.getAscent(), (int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(t.getName(), t.getX(), t.getY());
        t.setDrawn(true);
    }
```

Comment: It would help your question if you could post a [mre].

Comment: My attempts to have made a minimal reproducible example have appeared to fail as my attempts have all somehow solved the issue. I did however learn that If I try to modify the code I already posted, as long as there is a t.setDrawn(true), any draw statements in a if (!t.isDrawn()) block will not draw correctly. It is still a weird problem but I can work around it so this issue can be deemed solved.